# WPF: Is it standard that when a menuitem is disabled the icon is not greyed out?

Tags: wpf, icons, command

I have menuitems with icons and when it is disabled the icon remains the same.  Is it up to me to supply a disabled icon and, if so, does this also apply to menuitems bound to a command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is totally up to you. Because you have provided an Icon file. So you need to create Style.Trigger on MenuItem to give disabled effect on that. Either do a Opacity =0.5 or switch image to a different .ico image while IsEnabled=False in the template

Answer (score 13):

Found Jobi's answer helpful. Here's another way to accomplish the same thing using an Image Style and the MenuItem.Icon:

```
<MenuItem Header="Add ..." Command="{Binding AddCommand}" >
   <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Image Source="{StaticResource AddImage}" Style="{StaticResource EnableDisableImageStyle}"/>
   </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

And the Style:

```
<Style x:Key="EnableDisableImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="2.0" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Or just  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/> to match default MenuItem IsEnabled handling.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I had the same problem and and I could not find a satisfying answer to this question. Changing the opacity is quite simple, but what if you want to change the complete appearance of an Icon for a MenuItem. It took me two days to find a simple solution. Since I am pretty new to WPF I had to read through different concepts and Attached Properties was one that got me to my solution. Here is my code for changing the Icon depending on enabled/disabled MenuItem:

Here is the code, which defines the **Attached Properties** used by the style setter:

```
    public static class AltImageProvider
    {
        public static string GetAltImage(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(AltImageProperty);
        }
        public static void SetAltImage(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
             obj.SetValue(AltImageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AltImageProperty = 
               DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AltImage",typeof(string),typeof(AltImageProvider));

        public static string GetDefImage(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DefImageProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDefImage(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DefImageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DefImageProperty =
              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DefImage",typeof(string),typeof(AltImageProvider));
    }
```

Here is the code defining a style for Images like the Icons, that uses the **Attached Properties** (DefImage and AltImage):

```
    <Style x:Key="ImageDisableAltImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(local:AltImageProvider.DefImage)}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(local:AltImageProvider.AltImage)}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here is how to set the style and Icons for a MenuItem:

```
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageDisableAltImageStyle}" local:AltImageProvider.DefImage="/Icon/play_green.ico" local:AltImageProvider.AltImage="/Icon/play_grey.ico"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems odd, but all I did was create the following style. You'd think this is the built in behavior, but without this (like the OP), the image isn't dimmed. With this, the image is affected, too. And I don't need to modify anything else in my app.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This targets **only** the icons on all `MenuItem`s, without needing any keys and without affecting the look of the menu text.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Replace Frame with the actual icon container, e.g. Image -->
        <Style TargetType="Frame">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```